# Go Database Connector: go-sql-driver works, everything else "unknown driver, forgotten import?"

Tags: sql, go, postgresql-9.3

When I try to use database/sql in this way it compiles and works:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
```

But if I try to use postgres specific connectors it doesn't even compile:

```
import(
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

import(
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/jbarham/gopgsqldriver"
)
```

both fail with the error

```
sql: unknown driver "mysql" (forgotten import?)
```

I have done go get for both of these packages, and am really not sure why it is not compiling

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't even compile"? The error you've mentioned is a runtime error. What is the compilation failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you doing

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
```

later on?  When you import `"github.com/lib/pq"` for example, it registers itself by calling `sql.Register`, and then in the source of `sql.Open` you have:

```
func Open(driverName, dataSourceName string) (*DB, error) {
    driversMu.RLock()
    driveri, ok := drivers[driverName]
    driversMu.RUnlock()
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("sql: unknown driver %q (forgotten import?)", driverName)
    }
}
```

So, since you are no longer importing `mysql`, you need to change `sql.Open` to use the `pq` driver (or whichever one you end up picking).